# Keep calm and riddle me this

Tags: riddle

None of these idiots can match my sharp wits,
I devour these dullards and turn them into pricks.

What is it that I am?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are a

> Pencil Sharpener

Reasoning

> We can think of the sharpener as devouring the top of the pencil transofrming it from dull (dullard) to sharp (prick). It also contains a sharp blade.